# VueJS: v-bind:style only working conditionally in v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

Using `v-bind:style` works fine when binding `color`:

```
<p v-bind:style="{ color: '#' + tradingCardOption.BorderColorHex }">
  {{ tradingCardOption.ColorSetName }}
</p>
```

But, binding to the `background-color` does not work:

```
v-bind:style="{ background-color: '#' + tradingCardOption.BorderColorHex }"
```

And neither does binding to `border-top`:

```
v-bind:style="{ border-top: 15px solid + '#' + tradingCardOption.CornerColorHex }"
```

What could cause this to work so conditionally?

```html
<div v-for="tradingCardOption in tradingCardOptions">
  <div v-bind:style="{ background-color: '#' + tradingCardOption.BorderColorHex}" class="color-swatch " v-bind:class="{'selected' : $index == 0}" v-on:click="selectTradingCardOption(tradingCardOption, $event)">
    <div v-bind:style="{ border-top: 15px solid + '#' + tradingCardOption.CornerColorHex}"></div>
  </div> {{ tradingCardOption.BorderColorHex}}
  <p v-bind:style="{ color: '#' + tradingCardOption.BorderColorHex}"> {{ tradingCardOption.ColorSetName }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Object keys must be properly quoted if you use key names that are not valid identifiers. So `v-bind:style="{ background-color: '#' + tradingCardOption.BorderColorHex}"`

must be

```
v-bind:style="{'background-color': '#' + tradingCardOption.BorderColorHex}"
```

because `background-color` can't be used as object property key unless surrounded with quotes. Same with `border-color` it should be:

```
{'border-top': '15px solid #' + tradingCardOption.CornerColorHex}
```

Basically, you need to make sure parser doesn't try to interpret `-` character as minus and then think that `border` is a variable.